# Why exactly are NAND and NOR the only universal binary logic functions?

Tags: logic, binary

We know there are 16 possible binary logic functions:

```
A=0 A=0 A=1 A=1
B=0 B=1 B=0 B=1
------------------------------------
 0   0   0   0     ZERO
 0   0   0   1     AND
 0   0   1   0     ANDNOT
 0   0   1   1     A
 0   1   0   0     NOT-A-AND-B (whatever...) 
 0   1   0   1     B
 0   1   1   0     XOR
 0   1   1   1     OR
 1   0   0   0     NOR
 1   0   0   1     XNOR
 1   0   1   0     NOT-B
 1   0   1   1     ORNOT
 1   1   0   0     NOT-A
 1   1   0   1     IMPLIES
 1   1   1   0     NAND
 1   1   1   1     ONE
```

As is well known, all sixteen functions can be described using only NAND, and all sixteen functions can be described using only NOR.  But these are the *only* two such functions that are "universal."

This has always struck me as a very interesting asymmetry.  Why NAND and NOR but *not* AND and OR?  Why are these two special?  When all sixteen functions are numbered from 0..15 in the order above, NOR and NAND are numbers 8 and 14, neither at the beginning nor end of the list, nor right in the middle; they seem to hold arbitrary positions in the list.

Is there any underlying (simpler) concept that would motivate that *these two particular functions* are special in this way?  Or is it just one of those things that has no motivating underlying explanation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For universality, you needto be able to produce $1$ even when all inputs are $0$, hence $0\circ 0=1$. Similarly, $1\circ1=0$. This leaves us with only four functions. Two of these ($\neg A$ and $\neg B$) are in fact unary, so indeed only NAND and NOR remain.

Comment: This is very helpful but one tiny thing is left out (for me anyway): why exactly does universality require that there be a way to produce a 1 when the inputs are both 0, and to produce a 0 when both inputs are 1?  Whenever I think "yes that makes sense" I say "hmm wait but why exactly?"  The idea that "one of the inputs can always pass through" (if that is indeed the rationale) doesn't quite work for me...; maybe the reasoning is something else.  The reasoning *from* there to NAND and NOR is beautiful; it's the premise I need help with.

Comment: @RayToal Suppose that B(0, 0)=0 where B is some logic function.  Then it follows that where all the inputs equal 0, the formula will have value of 0. Consequently, every formula which just has function B is not a tautology.  Tautologies have to come as representable. So, if B(0, 0)=0, then no tautology can get represented, and thus we can only have a tautology when B(0, 0)=1. A similar argument leads us to conclude that if B(1, 1)=1, then no formula with just "B"'s and variables can represent a contradiction. So, if B can represent contradictions and tautologies, then B(0, 0)=1, and B(1, 1)=0.

Comment: @RayToal A corollary of that analysis comes as that no formula which just has implication or "implies" symbols qualifies as a contradiction.  In other words, if a formula only has implication symbols, then it comes as a true for at least one valuation of the variables.

Comment: I like to think about this problem as a binary operator on {0,1}. If this structure is a group, then it must be isomorphic to $C_2$ and hence any composite function you create must reduce to a series of NOT gates which is unary.